# How to perform operations with a list inside of a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to modify a dict of lists? If I have this dictionary:

```py
my_dict = {'numbers':[1,2,3],
           'numbers2':[4,5,6]
           'numbers3':[7,8,9]}
```

How can I multiply all numbers by 3? This is the output I want:

```py
my_dict = {'numbers':[3,6,9],
           'numbers2':[12,15,18]
           'numbers3':[21,24,27]}
```

Comment: `my_dict = { row: [x*3 for x in my_dict[row]] for row in my_dict }` could work.

Comment: It's just go through the `dict.items()` and do another loop for the x in values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you imagine are the logical steps to completing the task? For example, if you had a single one of the value lists, like `[1,2,3]`, could you write code to produce the required output list? If you had a key name and a value, do you see how to write code to assign the output list back into the dictionary? Do you know how to write code to repeat that process for each key/value pair in the dictionary?

Comment: If any of these steps is not known to you, they are all basic technique that you [can and should research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by following a tutorial or using a search engine. If you do know all of these steps, then exactly what difficulty do you encounter when putting them together?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not private tutorial service, nor intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation — and that is where you should be looking for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a dictionary comprehension:

```
{key: [j*3 for j in value] for key, value in my_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'numbers': [3, 6, 9], 'numbers2': [12, 15, 18], 'numbers3': [21, 24, 27]}
```